# Special Riemannian metric on the product

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, minimal-surfaces

Let $M^2$ be an orientable surface with boundary endowed with a Riemannian metric $g$. We know that if we put in the manifold $M \times \mathbb{R}$ the product metric $\overline{g} = g + dt^2$, then the slices $M_t = M \times \{t\}$ are totally geodesic and are free-boundary surfaces, which means that their boundary meet the boundary $\partial (M \times \mathbb{R}) = \partial M \times \mathbb{R}$ orthogonally.

Suppose now that we choose an angle $\theta \in (0, \pi)$. Is there a "natural" Riemannian metric $g_\theta$ on $M \times \mathbb{R}$ such that 
the slices $M_t$ are totally geodesic, meet the boundary of $M \times \mathbb{R}$ at a constant angle $\theta$ and $g_{\pi/2}$ agrees with the product metric $\overline{g}$? Is there an explicit formula?

**Remark**: Let $N_t$ be the unit normal to $M_t$ in the metric $g_\theta$, and $\overline{N}$ be the outward unit normal to $\partial M \times \mathbb{R}$ in this metric. We say that the slice $M_t$ meets the boundary $\partial M \times \mathbb{R}$ at an angle $\theta$ if 
$$g_\theta(N_t, \overline{N}) = \cos \theta$$
along $\partial M_t$.

This question was also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237696/special-riemannian-metric-on-the-product).

Comment: what about $k\cdot t^2\cdot g+dt^2$?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin what is $k$ and what happens when $t=0$?

Comment: $k$ is a constant so the metric is defined only for $t>0$, but if you reparametrize it by $\ln t$ you get a metric on the product $M\times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237696/special-riemannian-metric-on-the-product